# gridview.getElementsByTagName("input") is giving Inputs Zero Why?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

function ValidateNew() {

```
        var gridview = document.getElementById('ctl00_cp_GridViewKRIlib');

        if (gridview != null) {

            var Inputs = gridview.getElementsByTagName("input");

            for (i = 0; i < Inputs.length; i++) {

                if (Inputs[i].type == 'text') {

                    if (Inputs[i].value == "") {
                        alert('Enter the value!');
                        Inputs[i].focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am calling this function in

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:LinkButton ID="linkbuttonNew" runat="server" Text="New" CommandName="New" CommandArgument='<%#Container.DataItemIndex%>'
OnClientClick="javascript:return ValidateNew();">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

INPUTS Are Showing zero Why?

Comment: can you post whole gridview source ?

Comment: Actual HTML source would be helpful. Also, you can easily drop that `language="javascript"` - it's redundant.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  What inputs, I don't see any INPUTs in your code?  Or do you mean the inputs array is empty but you expect it to contain some elements?  We not seeing enough of your code to help.  BTW, popping up alerts in the way you seem to intend makes for a really poor user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks brittle:

```
var gridview = document.getElementById('ctl00_cp_GridViewKRIlib');
```

You're relying on knowing ASP.NET's generated ID for an HTML element, which at best reduces your code's portability and at worst simply won't work (for instance, if you change something else in the page). In the absence of any actual HTML to look at I'd suggest that line is the most likely source of error.

What you could do instead is pass the ID of the HTML element ASP.NET is generating into your JavaScript function, so the first two lines become

```
function ValidateNew(elementId) {

    var gridview = document.getElementById(elementId);
```

My ASP.NET is rusty so I'm not sure how best to get the ID and pass it into the JavaScript. ClientID is the property you need from the generated control, which you get in the `OnClientClick` attribute (a quick search found me [this page](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2005/06/23/2341.aspx), which may help). And you shouldn't have the "javascript:" prefix in your OnClientClick attribute value. The value of a JavaScript event handler attribute should be just JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been late. I guess this would have helped:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="someGrid" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

This would help you to use:

```
    var gridview = document.getElementById('someGrid');
```